# How to write stored procedures for Dynamic Table Creation in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench

1. Stored Procedure should create table by taking table name, column names, its datatype & size as user needed.
2. The procedure for inserting into a table is shown below. **I need to do creation of new table like this dynamic insertion through parameters.**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `AddCustomer`
    (FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(45),
     LAST_NAME VARCHAR(45),
     CITY VARCHAR(45) , 
     MOBILE_NO BIGINT,
     PANCARD_NO VARCHAR(45),
     DOB VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO customer_details 
    (FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY,MOBILE_NO,PANCARD_NO,DOB) 
    VALUES(FIRST_NAME,LAST_NAME,CITY,MOBILE_NO,PANCARD_NO,DOB);
END
```

Comment: Have you tried `PREPARED STATEMENTS` ?

Comment: you need to use a prepared statement with dynamic sql. mysql docs are a good resource to look for how to do that

Comment: I have used prepared statements. But how can I Manage the number of parameters as the different table have different number of fields and different datatype? That's where I got stuck.  I need to take dynamic fields and their datatype as parameter.